# Consume .NET services from Java

Tags: c#, java, url, service

I've made a .NET service in C# that can be accessed via

```
http://localhost:2586/Service1.asmx/AddPackage?username=acesda&description=no%20Description&state=New&location=Home
```

If I use the browser, The service works fine and I can see the XML result in browser.
But, if I use the following code in a Java application, I get an HTTP 400 error:

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:2586/Service1.asmx/AddPackage?adminName=admin&sessionID=1388849172471&packageOwner=user&description=iPhone 4s&state=new&location=iPhone 4s
```

Code:

```
    try {
            String parameters = String.format(PARAMETERS_TEMPLATE, adminName, sessionID, packageOwner, description, packageState, description, location);
            String url = String.format(PACKAGE_URL_TEMPLATE, "AddPackage", parameters);
            Document responseDocument = Utils.getRemoteXML(url, 1000);
            properties.put("success", Utils.isSuccesfull(responseDocument));
            properties.put("failReason", Utils.getMessage(responseDocument));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            properties.put("success", "false");
            properties.put("failReason", e.getMessage());
        }

    public static Document getRemoteXML(String url, int timeout) throws Exception {
        URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        Document document = (Document) builder.build(connection.getInputStream());
        return document;
    }
```

I must notice that I copied the address from exception, and it works in browser.
Thank you.

Comment: why there are spaces here :http://localhost:2586/Service1.asmx/AddPackage?adminName=admin&sessionID=1388849172471&packageOwner=user&description=**iPhone 4s**&state=new&location=**iPhone 4s**

Comment: The problem may be that your service is indigenous to the .Net application. I can say that from your URL. So, accessing it from a java application, while the local ASP server is not running will result in the error. I don't know if this'll work. Try to publish your service in **IIS** and then you may be able to consume it.

Comment: If I copy the exception address and paste it in Firefox, I received the desired XML. So no, there is no problem with the address. Maybe it has to do with something in Java code.

Comment: @GunnerAziz You were right. That space made everything a mess. It seems that the browser encode the spaces, so it works from there. Thank you.

Comment: wish i posted that on answer :P

Comment: Please do it. You deserve a vote.